# What is a Composer Package of Type composer-installer?

Tags: php, composer-php, composer-plugin

Composer allows users to create packages [that are composer plugins](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/plugins.md).  Plugins can subscribe to  events emitted during the regular use of a composer and *do things*.

Composer also allows users to create classes and objects [that are composer installers](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/custom-installers.md).  A Composer Installer in a class that can install files outside of the composer `vendor` folder.  The way you tell Composer about an installer is to create a composer plugin, and in the plugin's `activate` method you instantiate an installer and add it to composer's installation manager.

These are both concepts I came to understand by reading the above linked docs.  What I don't understand is, what is a composer *package* of type `composer-installer`.  I don't see any mention of these in the docs

There appear to be around [115 of these packages](https://packagist.org/packages/list.json?type=composer-installer) in the packagist registry.  I've taken a look at [one of these](https://github.com/AOEpeople/composer-installers) and it *appears* to be a package you can add as a composer plugin, but that composer will recognize as an installer. I'm not familiar enough with how composer installers to know if this is correct, or if there's different functionality in these `composer-installer` package.

What are these packages?  Was this some sort of alpha feature of composer installers ended up being abandoned?  Or is this a future feature?  Regardless -- will packages of type `composer-installer` be supported into the future, or is this some weird vestigial thing that's best to leave behind?

Comment: Not sure if you have seen https://github.com/composer/installers which seems to give a more comprehensive list of packages and some more documentation.

Comment: I have seen that repo, but thank you Nigel.  I was not, however, able to find reference to the `type: composer-installer` packages in there.  Did I miss them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `composer-installer` was meant for packages that implemented the custom installer.

Currently, it's recommended that the type for this custom installers is set to  `composer-plugin`, but it used to be `composer-installer`. I imagine this was changed around the time when the package [`composer/installers`](https://github.com/composer/installers) was developed and released (which makes many of the old custom installers obsolete anyway).

The first official release of `composer/installers` was [on Jun 2014](https://github.com/composer/installers/releases?after=v1.0.25), and with a bit of digital archaeology we can see that the documentation changes on `https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/custom-installers.md` happened just a bit earlier than that:

#### [August 19 2013](http://web.archive.org/web/20130819222227/https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/custom-installers.md)

`type:composer-installers` is still recommended:
[image: screenshot showing a composer.json file using type:composer-installers]

#### [September 06 2013](http://web.archive.org/web/20130906181145/https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/custom-installers.md)

Changes were afoot, and briefly it was recommended to set the type to `composer-installer-plugin´:
[image: screenshot showing a composer.json file using type:composer-installer-plugin]

#### [September 27 2013](http://web.archive.org/web/20130927215901/https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/custom-installers.md)

By now we already have the current `composer-plugin` recommendation, which hasn't change since:
[image: screenshot showing a composer.json file using type:composer-plugin]

---

#### tldr;

Forget about `composer-installers`, that type has not been used in some time. A good amount of those 115 packages are likely abandoned. The type one should use for custom installers is, and has been for some years: `composer-plugin`.

Comment: Thank you yivi -- that's exactly the information I wanted to find.